# What's the average time for order confirmation and fulfillment for brokers in intraday trading?

Tags: stocks, trading, brokerage

I've been flirting with the idea of automated, algorithmic trading applications and have been running simulations for several trading strategies with historical, intraday stock prices. There's one aspect which I haven't been considering when simulating those strategies, however, which is the delay to be expected between when an order is sent to the brokerage service and when it is confirmed and fulfilled.

I've never practiced intraday trading out of said simulations, so I have no idea how long the confirmation and fulfillment of an order would take: it would make a difference in profits, however, since, for example, a delay of five minutes between posing an order and actually obtaining a result from the trade would make price fluctuations of ~10 minutes or less impossible to profit from, even if my algorithm was capable of detecting trends in such short notice.

How long should I expect that process to take?
(I'm planning to use Alpaca API for buying and selling securities)

Comment: What order type are you using? Market orders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a trading platform, the expected delay for confirmation of a filled order is a fraction of a second.  As soon as your trade is filled, you receive an update and your account page immediately reflects the new position or the removal of an existing position.